# How to keep two HTML input fields in sync (without Javascript)?

Tags: html

Is there a simple way to keep these two HTML input fields in sync (**without** using Javascript)?

```
<div class="hide_on_mobile">
  <input type="text" name="message"/>
</div>

<div class="hide_on_desktop">
  <input type="text" name="message"/>
</div>
```

The problem is that one of the two is always hidden from the user but nonetheless exists in the HTML. So saving a form does not work right now on desktop because the value is always overwritten by the second (empty) field.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: First, you can't as HTML is a read-only document that does now execute anything just as syncing would require. Second its an X-Y to me. There is no reason to have the same input element twice instead of applying different styles to it depending on the device with `media queries`

Comment: you can't, the closes way would be using inline javascript in html attributes onchange or oninput

Comment: If you absolutely need 2 inputs, can't you also use 2 forms?

Comment: Why display different inputs on different resolutions anyway? Doesn't make sense

Comment: @tacoshy regarding the first part of you comment that's not entirely true, HTML does process the input, see e.g. the constraint validation it does when the `pattern` attribute is set, or even just the `placeholder` attribute, so we could imagine a feature where two inputs are linked. Actually, there is a feature request that comes quite often that could handle this: a CSS `element()` function which could clone an element somewhere else in the page. So it's not like it's fundamentally impossible, it's just that *currently* it is.

Comment: @Kaiido I know - it's called **didactiv reduction**. Nearly everything has exceptions. You will always hear that you are not allowed to run through a red light. It's not true either, there are many exceptions such as right-hand turns, making space for emergency vehicles...

Comment: But your comment was inferring that it is inherent to how HTML works that it's not possible, and thus would never be possible. Nobody said that you are unable to cross at the red light. My point is that there is nothing that actually prevents such a feature to exist. Maybe it will someday. And saying that HTML is read-only is misleading.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. You can sort it out on the server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I need two different elements due to presentational reasons (can't be solved with CSS only).

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score -1):

Using to input fields with the same name attribute will, anyway, leads to conflict.
The solution could be that you specify the "name" attribute for each input and handle them eparately on your backend.
Something like this:

```
<div class="hide_on_mobile">
   <input type="text" name="message_desktop"/>
</div>

<div class="hide_on_desktop">
  <input type="text" name="message_mobile"/>
</div>
```

*I do not think that ther is a way to keep fields in sync without JS.*